# Teamspeak 3 text-to-speech chatting

Tags: voice-chat, teamspeak

I've been looking for a Teamspeak 3 plugin that will convert text to speech for everyone in the channel.

I know Teamspeak has a text-to-speech system in place for announcements but I would like to be able to type the window and have it converted to speech so other people can hear me.  I know Teamspeak has a text chat system but unfortunately it's a bit inconvenient for everyone to switch windows in a game.

So has anyone come across such a plugin or a way to do this in teamspeak 3?  If no one has I may decide to make the plugin myself.

Comment: But if you can't switch windows to type in a message in the chat box, how would you switch windows to type into a text-to-voice window?

Comment: because I don't care if I have to alt+tab.  I just don't expect everyone in my channel to alt+tab to read anything.

Comment: Mumble does this natively and is free, open source :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a plugin recommendation. This question might be suitable for reformat, but considering it is 4 years old and the asker has not logged in to Arqade in at least a year, I do not believe any further effort will add value to the site.

Comment: @Timelord64 Sure I guess.  I'm not editing a five year old question.

Answer (score 0):

[The FAQ](http://teamspeak.com/?page=faq&cat=ts3client#ts3client_where_is_tts) seems to imply TS3 supports Text to Speech natively (and tells you how to set the soundpack for it). I've never used it myself but a variety of results from a Google search seems to prove that it works.

Comment: yes teamspeak supports text to speech natively.  What I'm talking about is the ability to type something and it is converted to speech for everyone in my channel.  By default all text-to-speech does is say who is entering channels opposed to just playing a noise.